# Does the Helper Module have to be in App_Code for MVC to recognize when using VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, app-code

When I have my Helpers in the App_Code Directory of my APS.NET MVC VB Application, I can type <%=HTML.ImageUrl("myImage.gif")%>

If I move it to another folder I get Errors.
I assume I can import the Application Namespace to get it to work, but is that necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the namespace your using put into the web.config?

```
<pages>
     <namespaces>
          <add namespace="Your.Name.Space" />
     </namespaces>
</pages>
```